# text missing in span tag when doing web scraping using beautiful soup4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text from the following html code:
`<span id="numrefs">(0)</span>`
My code is as follows:

```
container = soup.findAll("span", {"id":"numrefs"})
print(cotainer)
print(cotainer[0].text)
```

I think I should be able to get the text, which is (0), using the second print. But the result of my code is as follows:

```
[<span id="numrefs"></span>]
```

I could not get any text in the span tag. The second print function returned nothing here. What is happening here?

Comment: The information you have provided so far is not enough to tell you why your output is missing desired values? It may be the content of that site generates dynamically.

Comment: yes, this number is actually the number of cited times of an academic paper. So, I assume it should be dynamic although I don't know much about html. Is it possible to scrape this sort of data?

Comment: Sure, there are always alternatives. In fact if you check out the bounty questions, you can have several answers there as to how you can play with dynamic sites. Check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Thank you. I checked that answer. It seems that there was a controlling script in that case. In my case, the text (0) is originally in the span tag. This is the webpage I am trying to scraping. [link](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-43-1-1) What I am trying to scape is the cited number on the left side of the page. Do you think this is the same as in that case?

Comment: I could not find any value of that id `numrefs` in that webpage. Check out [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4zvpt09pus04na/Untitled.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: that's interesting, maybe it's because of the browser. Anyway, I think it should be the dynamic data thing. I will do my research on this. Thank you!

Comment: i think i found the reason for this. This cited number is only available to the subscribers only. If you are not a subscriber, you will not see those numbers. I just realized this after I came back home. I can see those numbers using my university Internet access.However, I can still not scrape those data even if i'm using the university internet. Is this dynamic data?